# ¿Cómo puedo insertar una línea en un archivo de texto mediante php?

Tags: php

he creado un sistema de placas en el cual se introduce en la tabla (badges_definitions) los datos cómo la id, el código de placa (el nombre de la imagen que seleccionó), y la id del usuario que subió la placa. Pero no sé cómo incluir una línea a un archivo de texto con los datos (el título de la placa y la descripción) que fueron colocados en el formulario en php.

*Ejemplo de la línea en el archivo de texto (external_flash_texts.txt)*

```
badge_desc_NOMBREDELAPLACA=DESCRIPCIÓN DE LA PLACA
badge_name_NOMBREDELAPLACA=TÍTULO DE LA PLACA
```

*Codigo php*

```
if(isset($_POST['subirColor']))
         {

             $nombre_img = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
          $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
          $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

          $nombre_img2 = $_FILES['imagen2']['name'];
          $tipo2 = $_FILES['imagen2']['type'];
          $tamano2 = $_FILES['imagen2']['size'];


          if (($nombre_img == NULL) || ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] >= 500000)) 
          {
               // La Imagen 1 no ha sido ingresada
                 echo '<div class="alert red">Debes ingresar las dos Placas en los dos formatos PNG y GIF, has olvidado la placa en formato GIF.</div>';
          } 

          $TipoDeImagenVerificacion1 = pathinfo($nombre_img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

          if ($TipoDeImagenVerificacion1 != "gif")
          {
               // La Imagen 1 no es GIF
               echo '<div class="alert red">El formato de la placa no es GIF.</div>';
          } 

          $CodigoBadge = explode('.gif',$nombre_img);

          if (($nombre_img2 == NULL) || ($_FILES['imagen2']['size'] >= 500000)) 
          {
               // La Imagen 1 no ha sido ingresada
                 echo '<div class="alert red">Debes ingresar las dos Placas en los dos formatos PNG y GIF, Has olvidado la placa en formato PNG.</div>';
          }

          $titulo = filter($_POST['titulo']);
          $des = filter($_POST['des']);

          if($titulo == "" || empty($titulo)){
               // Titulo esta vacio
                 echo '<div class="alert red">Debes ingresar un titulo para la Placa.</div>';
          }
          if($des == "" || empty($des)){
               // Titulo esta vacio
                 echo '<div class="alert red">Debes ingresar una descripcion para la Placa.</div>';
          }



          $repeat = $db->query("SELECT * FROM badge_definitions WHERE badge = '".$CodigoBadge[0]."'");
             if($repeat->num_rows > 0){
                  echo '<div class="alert red">Ya existe una placa con el mismo Código.</div>';
              }else{

                  $DicGif = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$DicGif.$nombre_img);
                   $DicPNG = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name'],$DicPNG.$nombre_img);
                 // $db->query("INSERT INTO cms_logs_upbadges (username, badge, type, time) VALUES ('". $user['username'] ."', '".$CodigoBadge[0]."', 'badge', '". time() ."')");            
                  // $db->query("INSERT INTO cms_stafflogs (username, action, message, rank, userid, timestamp) VALUES ('". $user['username'] ."','Agrego una nueva placa', 'Agrego la placa ".$CodigoBadge[0]."', '". $user['rank'] ."', '". $user['id'] ."', '".date("Y-m-d ")."')");
                  $db->real_query("INSERT INTO badge_definitions (badge,user_id,time) VALUES ('".$CodigoBadge[0]."','".HK_Id."','". time() ."')");
                  // $db->query("INSERT INTO client_external_badge_texts (badge_code, badge_title, badge_desc) VALUES ('".$CodigoBadge[0]."', '".$titulo ."', '".$des."')");
                 // $_SESSION['GOOD_RETURN'] = "La placa [".$CodigoBadge[0]."";
              }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

creo q lo mejor seria con file_put_contents, por dejarlo en una sentencia. Quedaria asi:

```
file_put_contents(ruta_al_archivo,"$nombre=$desc\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

El final de linea puede ser "\n" o "\r\n" depende desde donde leas luego el archivo Linux o Windows respectivamente.
[Aqui puedes aprender mas sobre file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php)

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi la mejor forma de escribir archivos de textos es con el método de cadena HEREDOC te pongo un ejemplo simple

```
mi_variable = 555
$str_conf = <<<EOD

Hola puedo escribir texto aquí
hacer saltos de línea
e incluso decir que mi variable vale $mi_variable 

EOD;

$archivo = fopen("mi_archivo.txt", "w");
fwrite($archivo, PHP_EOL .$str_conf);
fclose($archivo);
```

Este es un ejemplo que guarda el string en un archivo de texto solo para probar, pero puedes guardar esa variable (`$str_conf` en este caso) en la tabla de datos y te quedará igualmente formateada cuando la llames y la despliegues en HTML.

Por lo que incorporando un Input para el Título y un Input  para la Descripción, solo tendrás que concatenar ambos textos e ingresarlos a tu tabla.

El tema es que escribes normalmente y queda formateado como lo escribes.
[Más información aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php) (Ejemplo #2):

[Espero me haya explicado bien]